# How to make an element that is fixed disapear behind a non fixed element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three elements that are fixed, when they reach a certain section in the page, I want them to transition into the next element,but not just disappear and change. At the divides I want to be able to see the top fixed element half and the bottom fixed element half. EX: If the top element is red and bottom element is blue then at the divide I should see a box that has half red and half blue.

Here is what I have so far, but right now each element just disappears, I want it to appear that it is sliding under the next fixed element. (I messed around with the z-index but this solution didn't work b/c both items are fixed to the same spot)

HTML:

```
<body id="body">

  <div id="background">
  </div>

  <div id="red">
    <div class="fixedContainer" id="something">
      This is Just a test
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mdl-grid" id="blue">
    <div class="fixedContainer2" id="something2">
      This is Just a test2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mdl-grid" id="green">
    <div class="fixedContainer3" id="something3">
      This is Just a test3
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#background {
  height: 900px;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 1;
}

#red {
  height: 900px;
  background-color: red;
}

#blue {
  height: 900px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#green {
  height: 900px;
  background-color: green;
}

.fixedContainer {
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 2em;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.fixedContainer2 {
  z-index: 5;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #ffff00;
  padding: 2em;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.fixedContainer3 {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #dd1144;
  padding: 2em;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

JS

```
$('#something').hide();
$('#something2').hide();
$('#something3').hide();

$(document).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() < 700) {
    $('#something').hide();
    $('#something2').hide();
    $('#something3').hide();
  } else if ($(document).scrollTop() > 700 && $(document).scrollTop() < 1580) {
    $('#something3').show();
    $('#something2').hide();
    $('#something').hide();
  } else if ($(document).scrollTop() > 1580 && $(document).scrollTop() < 2490) {
    $('#something2').show();
    $('#something3').hide();
    $('#something').hide()
  } else if ($(document).scrollTop() > 2490) {
    $('#something2').hide();
    $('#something').show()
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zs4emw00/4/

Comment: well you probably would need to change the code so it does not get hidden, and change the height based on how much overhang it is.

Comment: @epascarello, Removing the jQuery is no problem. Can you please define overhang...I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the https://jsfiddle.net/zs4emw00/5/

You create an overall container and set that container to `overflow: hidden;`
Then have that fixedContainer set to `position:absolute`. The jquery part is to always keep all the `fixedContainer` at the top of the window.

HTML:

```
  <div id="background">
  </div>

  <div id="red" class="container">
    <div class="fixedContainer" id="something">
      This is Just a test
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mdl-grid container" id="blue" >
    <div class="fixedContainer" id="something2">
      This is Just a test2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mdl-grid container" id="green">
    <div class="fixedContainer" id="something3">
      This is Just a test3
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#background {
    height:900px;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 1;
}
.container{
    position:relative;
    height:900px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#red {
    background-color: red;
}

#blue {
    background-color: blue;
}

#green {
    background-color: green;
}

.fixedContainer {
    z-index: 10;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#ddd;
    padding: 2em;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var $target = $('container');
  var winHeight = $(window).scrollTop();
  var offsetArr = $('.container').each(function(){
    var top = $(this).offset().top;
    var difference = winHeight - top;
    $(this).find('.fixedContainer').css('top',difference);
  })

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This is 90% of what I wanted. The only problem with this is that the box is stuck to the top of the div. I was really going for that fixed effect of it sitting in the middle. I am tinkering with your jsFiddle now to see if I can figure out that last piece.

Comment: Ah I just added margin-top: 200px; to the .fixedContainer and it did the job. Thanks Again Stanley